# How to put elements on top of each other in the same xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I have more than one button, or a button and a text view in the same location in one layout but one on top of the other?

I want to have a button that is hidden most of the time, but occasionally will have a non intrusive popup that will prompt something. The rest of the time there will be a text view there that is a different size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at [RelativeLayouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

They use `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` to position elements below/above other elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` or `TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` depending on your condition and you may not need to put elements on top of each other in the layout.