# Elements overlapping on top of each other in relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have created an Activity and used `RelativeLayout` which comes in by default in Android Studio.

I am trying to place a button just before my `TextView` but I am unable to do that.

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/sachin_jain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Looks like I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put elements on top of each other in the same xml layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888337/how-to-put-elements-on-top-of-each-other-in-the-same-xml-layout)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I have found out is: Use `android:layout_below` instead of `android:layout_alignTop` / `android:layout_alignRight`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:text="My First Activity with Relative Layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/heading"
    android:layout_margin="20px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Here is the screenshot:

> [image: Snapshot with working Relative Layout]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want a button first and a textview second. Then you can do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/sachin_jain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your problem was that you had:

```
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/heading"
```

in your button that made both the view align top of eachother.

Comment: ..Your solution does not work as well. `layout_alignRight` and 'layout_alignTop` will align the button's top and right with text view and hence they will overlap with each other again